# Why is this correlation (seemingly?) wrong?

Tags: mathematica-online

```
 popDensity[k_] := 
     QuantityMagnitude[AdministrativeDivisionData[k, "PopulationDensity"]]
       
   
ResourceUpdate[
      "Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"] // Quiet
    data = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", 
       "USStates"];
    
    usaStateCases[s_] := 
     Select[data, MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], First[#]] &][
        All, #ConfirmedCases["LastValue"] &] // Normal // First
    
    usaStateDeaths[s_] := 
     Select[data, MatchQ[Interpreter["USState"][s], First[#]] &][
        All, #Deaths["LastValue"] &] // Normal // First
    
    usaStateCases["California"] 
    
    usaStateDeaths["California"] 
    
 
    
        
    Table[{states1[[k]], popDensity[states1[[k]]], 
       usaStateDeaths[states1[[k]]]}, {k, Length@states1}] // MatrixForm
    
    Correlation[
     Table[popDensity[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}], 
     Table[usaStateDeaths[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}]]
    Correlation[Table[popDensity[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}], 
     Table[usaStateCases[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}]]
       
  Deaths = 
      Table[{k, popDensity[states1[[k]]], 
        usaStateDeaths[states1[[k]]]}, {k, Length@states1}];
 
    Cases1 = Table[{k, popDensity[states1[[k]]], 
        usaStateCases[states1[[k]]]}, {k, Length@states1}];
```

I am in particular interested in the seemingly wrong estimate:

Correlation[Table[popDensity[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}],
Table[usaStateCases[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}]]

Comment: Too long, didn't read. Can you please construct a minimal example of your question?

Comment: popDensity[s] is the population density in state s.

Correlation[
 Table[popDensity[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}], 
 Table[usaStateDeaths[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}]]
Correlation[Table[popDensity[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}], 
 Table[usaStateCases[states1[[k]]], {k, 1, Length@states1}]]


usaStateCases[s] is number of covid-19 positive tests that have been performed.  usaStateDeaths[s] is number of deaths from covid-19 in state k.  states1[[k]] is the k-th state (or D.C.).

Comment: With such an involved example, copy-and-pasteable code is crucial.  Your code cannot be copied and pasted into Mathematica, and I'm not going to work so hard to get it to work.

As @Roman suggested, can you give a minimal working example?  For example, from a dataset that isn't hundreds of lines long?  Maybe just some random data (with a particular seed to make it reproducible)?

Comment: I thought I fixed it.